# SVG to SWF, AVI converter

Tags: svg, flash, avi

I have animated SVG using SMIL. However I would need to export to other formats.

Do you know any program that would convert animated SVG to SWF, GIF, AVI (or any other video format)?

Comment: you could first convert it to a swf http://svg.brothersoft.com/svg-to-swf-converter.html and then use moyea's swf to avi converter.

Comment: btw i have moyea software so if you want i could do the second half for you. email me the file (see profile)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This conversion is easy with ffmpeg in two steps.

**Step 1**: Generate a movie from your screen.

1. Open your animated SVG in Mozilla Firefox or Internet Explorer.
2. Use this command in a terminal:

   ```
   ffmpeg -s 1440x640 -r 25 -f x11grab -i :0.0 -b 6000k out.avi
   ```

   With:

   - **-s** specify the format of your animation (here 1440x640 px).
   - **-r** the frames per seconds (Here 25).
   - **-f** the selection of your screen.
   - **-b** the quality (6000k is good quality).
   - **out.avi** name and format of the file.
3. Now watch your animation in full screen mode (F11). If your animation is looped it's better.
4. Stop the recording (Ctrl + C)

**Step 2**: Save only the interesting part

Use this command in a terminal:

```
ffmpeg -i out.avi -b 6000k -r 25 -t "00:00:10" -ss "00:00:09" "final.avi"
```

With:

- **-i** the file to cut.
- **-b** the quality.
- **-r** the frame rate.
- **-t** the duration of recording (Here 10s).
- **-ss** the recording start (Here at 9s).
- **final.avi** the output fil.

Now you have an .avi file

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't use ffmpeg, however the approach was the same - run it in a browser and screen-capture it.